# Jquery touch devices contents show/hide

Tags: jquery

Content have to replace on touch start & touch device. My present code becomes to normal once touch is removed.

On first touch, it have to show hidden ("item-over") content. on second touch, it have to show ("item-short") content. On third touch, it have show "item-over" content again.

**HTML**

```
<li>
  <img data-swap-image="images/ticked-small.png" data-ng-mouseleave="swapImageSrc()" data-ng-mouseenter="swapImageSrc()" alt="" src="images/tick.png" class="icon ng-scope" id="item_1">
  <span id="item_1-short" style="display: block;">Default content</span>
  <span style="display: none;" id="item_1-over">Content to display on touch</span>
</li>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#'+divId).on("touchstart", function() {
    $('#'+divId+'-short').hide();
    $('#'+divId+'-over').show();
});

$('#'+divId).on("touchend", function() {
    $('#'+divId+'-short').show();
    $('#'+divId+'-over').hide();
});
```

**Code provided by user:**

```
 $('img'+'#'+divId).on("touchstart", function(e) {
        $("[id$=short], [id$=over]").toggle()
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, Updated (v2)

Try

```
   var divId = "item_1";
   $("img#" + divId).on("touchstart", function(e) {
      $(this)
      .siblings("[id="+divId+"-short], [id="+divId+"-over]")
      .toggle()
   });
```

See [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```js
var divId = "item_1";
$("img#" + divId).on("touchstart", function(e) {
    $(this).siblings("[id="+divId+"-short], [id="+divId+"-over]").toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <img data-swap-image="images/ticked-small.png" data-ng-mouseleave="swapImageSrc()" data-ng-mouseenter="swapImageSrc()" alt="" src="images/tick.png" class="icon ng-scope" id="item_1" />
  <span id="item_1-short" style="display: block;">Default content</span>
  <span style="display: none;" id="item_1-over">Content to display on touch</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code..  Span id toggle have to be based on <img> id. when user touch <img>, toggle function have to trigger. Your present code works based on <span> trigger.

Comment: Hi.. Sorry to trouble you again.. Here we are getting ID names dynamically like "item_1", "item_2", "item_3".. etc..  We cant use constant ID boss.  Thanks

Comment: @Venkiweb Substitute `$(/* ID names dynamically like "item_1", "item_2", "item_3" */)` for `$("img#item_1")`  ?

Comment: Hi.. we are calling this function in around 50 elements on different pages. Desktop version works fine. Only for touch devices we cant able to make it like in desktop.

Comment: @Venkiweb Only 4 elements appear at OP ? If possible , can post full `html`, `js` ? If valid selectors for both dynamic images , spans , piece should toggle n-spans at n-image `touchstart` events . To try piece at desktop chrome / chromium , try opening `console` -> `drawer` -> `Emulation` -> `Sensor` -> `Emulate touch screen` .

Comment: Hi... Thanks for your help.. almost done.. Check my "Code provided by user code". This code works fine. But, if item1 touched, it opens item2, item3. Also close all items same time. Is it possible to open only in 1 item at a time and close others?

Comment: @Venkiweb See updated post. If the `html` is same throughout , `span` elements would be `siblings` of `touchstart` `event.target` , `image` , within `li`

Comment: Thanks.. its working.. Please update your answer above to close this issue. Thanks again for your valuable answer. ng-mousedown & ng-mouseup correct command for hover effect in touch device? Whether it will affect desktop version?